# Can somebody please describe to me what this algorithm does?

Tags: algorithm, iteration

```
t ≤ n

algorithm unknown(a[t...n])
    if t = n 
        return n
    sol ← unknown(a[t + 1...n])
    if a[t] < a[sol]
        return t
    else
        return sol
```

I'm trying to figure it out for like 2 hours now and start feeling dumb, it would be nice if someone could help me thanks! for unknwon[2, 3, 7, 2, 8]

Comment: Without knowing `unknown`, how would you expect to know? Is that a mistake? Is that intended to be a recursive call of `loop`??

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the array

Answer (score 2):

The function uses recursion to find the index of the minimum value in a given (sub)array.

The base case of recursion is when the given subarray has only one value: in that case, the return value is the index of that one element.

The recursive case is dealt with as follows:

- Using recursion, get the index of the minimum value in a subarray that excludes the first element.
- Check which is the least of the two: the first element or the minimum value located by recursion. Return the corresponding index.

Here is a translation into JavaScript. It is run with an example array as input:

```js
function unknown(a, t) {
    if (t == a.length - 1) 
        return t;
    let sol = unknown(a, t + 1);
    if (a[t] < a[sol])
        return t;
    else
        return sol;
}

let a = [4,2,6,9,7,3,8];
let i = unknown(a, 0);
console.log(`Minimum is at index ${i}, with value ${a[i]}`);
```